# Kaarite rebuttal of the new testament

Tags: christianity, publications, non-rabbinic-judaism

A while ago I was pointed to a Kaarite rebuttal of the New testament from a few centuries ago. I found it online with an interactive chapter by chapter format. Now I can't remember the name or find it by searches. Is anyone familiar with this piece and what is it called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that the work you are referring to is *[Chizuk Emunah](https://archive.org/details/faithstrengthene00trok)*, "Faith Strengthened" by Isaac Troki, it is my recollection that this was relatively well received in traditional circles as well.

Comment: What a nice little book!  I just made it through the first half dozen chapters so far...good stuff!